# Where is the csv data in response?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am using `fetch` to get the `CSV` with the following:

```
const csv = await fetch('https://www.mysite-com/admin/order?_export_=page%3A1', {credentials: 'include'});
```

Here is the printout of the `csv':

```
CSV is:  Response {
  size: 0,
  timeout: 0,
  [Symbol(Body internals)]:
   { body:
      Gunzip {
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 7,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        _transformState: [Object],
        bytesWritten: 0,
        _handle: [Zlib],
        _hadError: false,
        _writeState: [Uint32Array],
        _outBuffer:
         <Buffer 3c 21 44 4f 43 54 59 50 45 20 68 74 6d 6c 3e 0a 3c 68 74 6d 6c 3e 0a 3c 68 65 61 64 3e 0a 20 20 3c 6d 65 74 61 20 63 68 61 72 73 65 74 3d 22 75 74 66 ... >,
        _outOffset: 0,
        _level: -1,
        _strategy: 0,
        _chunkSize: 16384,
        _defaultFlushFlag: 2,
        _finishFlushFlag: 2,
        _nextFlush: -1,
        _info: undefined },
     disturbed: false,
     error: null },
  [Symbol(Response internals)]:
   { url: 'https://www.mysite-com/admin/auth/login',
     status: 200,
     statusText: 'OK',
     headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object] } } }
```

The `chunkSize` of `16384` seems matching the file size I am downloading. But how to retrieve the data from teh `csv`? Tried `csv.text()` with error.

UPDATE：

Tried the below:

```
const csv = fetch('https://www.mysite-com/admin/order?_export_=page%3A1', {credentials: 'include'})
                             .then(r => r.text)
                             .catch(err => {
                              console.log("Error downloading order csv.", err);
                             });
if (csv) {
       fs.writeFile('./tmp/order/order.xls', csv, 'utf8', err => {
        console.log("Error saving downloaded order csv.", err);
      });
```

Returned `Error saving downloaded order csv null`

Comment: did you await for response.text()? what kind of error did you get?

Comment: what is your "content-encoding" that is returned by your backend of this request?

Comment: `drinchev`, the content is utf8 text in csv format.

Comment: `Sim Dim`, the error is `response.text() is not function`. the structure used was `const csv = fetch(url).then(r => r.text())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const csv = fetch('https://www.mysite-com/admin/order?_export_=page%3A1', {
    credentials: 'include'
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.text;
  })
  .then(function(resText) {
    console.log(resText);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` returns a promise to a `Response`. On that response, you should be able to call `await response.text()` to get the string.